# How do I close a form using app Controller?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, mvp

There is an AppController - where all forms are managed.

Below in appController I manage forms, but there I can only open them. Immediately and to the question, and how to close? Also, when I opened it on top of the same window, the same window opened. How do I get rid of this? I've tried form == null form.IsDisposed, but it's a bit wrong.

```
public class AppController : IAppController
{
private readonly Mainform_medicalrecord _mainform;
public IDataContext DataContext { get; }
public IMessageService MessageService { get; }

public AppController(IDataContext dataContext, IMessageService messageService)
{
DataContext = dataContext ??
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataContext));
MessageService = messageService ??
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(messageService));

var vm = new MainViewModel(this);
_mainForm = new MainForm_MedicalRecord(vm);
}

public Form GetMainForm()
{
return _mainForm;
}

public void ShowCardView()
{
var vm = new CardViewModel(this);
var form = new CardView(vm);
form.Owner = _mainForm;
form.ShowDialog();
}
}
```

**ViewMode**

```
public CardViewModel(AppController appController)
{
_appController = appController
?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appController));
}
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appController));
}
```

**CardView**

```
public CardView(CardViewModel cardViewModel)
{
InitializeComponent();
_viewModel = cardViewModel ??
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cardViewModel));
}
```

I will add... when opening the form, it is duplicated, which I do not need at all. Help me please.

Comment: Please translate your title, as it's very likely to attract close or down votes for the question not being in English. As for your "question", what is it? You haven't asked anything.

Comment: Title:  How to close forms through ViewModels (according to google)

Comment: I Google-Translated the Title, feel free to improve it, if it is incorrect @Миша Демин

Comment: @Fildor I'm sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about :)

Comment: So, you are opening new Forms as Dialog ... Usually, Dialogs close "themselves". How is your UI working? Do you actually want to have something like a Main Application Form and free floating child windows? Or more like a tabbed design?

Comment: ^^ By "free floating" I mean something like [MDI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications)

Comment: @Fildor I can open the same form many times, which I absolutely do not need. That's why I put `ShowDialog` on for a while, I would like it to work stably with `Show()`. Why does the `Close()` method not perceive(

Comment: @Fildor Yes you are right.

Comment: In `ShowCardView` you create a new Form on every call. What I guess you want instead is create the Form _once_ and reuse it. That means you need to save a reference to it in your AppController class as a private class field. Then you can check, if it is null. If it is, create one, if it is not null, just show that one. If the Form can close itself, remember to null the reference in the AppController.

Comment: ... then, when you have that reference, you should also be able to `Close` it from the AppController.

Comment: @Fildor I apologize, of course, but could you give us a small example for further action?

Comment: @Fildor I can't understand your thought a little, and I'm sorry for that. Can be as any on example demonstrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate my thoughts from the comments and to give an example:

```
private CardView cardView = null;

public void ShowCardView()
{
    if( null == cardView )
    {
        var vm = new CardViewModel(this);
        cardView = new CardView(vm);
        cardView.Owner = _mainForm;
    }
    cardView.Show();
}
```

Mind, that this is **not threadsafe**! Here, your controller would only make a new (separate) Form if there isn't already one. This avoids "duplicate" Forms.

You should add some thread safety measures to this code, though.

If you have that you could add a Close Method:

```
// Again: TODO Add thread safety!
public void CloseCardView()
{
     cardView?.Close();
     cardView = null;
}
```

... if you really need it. I'd argue that it would probably suffice to hide the Form.